# HREF using # not working

Tags: html, href

I have the following two hrefs:

```
        <li><a id="Totals" class="btn btn-info" style="display: none;" href="#section-fund-totals">Totals</a></li>
        <li><a id="CommonStock" class="btn btn-info" style="display: none;" href="#CommonStock">Common Stock</a></li>
```

and the following two divs further down the page:

```
            <div id="section-fund-totals" class="sectionanchor">
            </div>
```

and this

```
            <div id="CommonStock" class="sectionanchor">
            </div>
```

When I click Totals, I am taken to that part of the page, but when I click Common Stock, WHICH IS SET UP EXACTLY LIKE Totals, nothing happens.

Why not?

I might as well add that this is the url generated for the working one

```
http://localhost:50981/Holding/Account?account_id=DISCO%20%20%20%20%20#section-fund-totals
```

and this is for the other

```
http://localhost:50981/Holding/Account?account_id=DISCO%20%20%20%20%20#CommonStock
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should have the different id because you have already added CommonStock id to that div element .add another name for id then it will work fine

Answer (score 1):

It is not setup the same because you have applied the `id="CommonStock"` to two elements, the `a` and the `div`. So the link targets itself.

IDs must be unique in the document.

So change the id of the `a` to `id="CommonStockLink"` or whatever else that is different than `CommonStock` and you will be fine.